# Ayuda con expresión regular irreport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Hola tengo un problema con la siguiente expresión regular en ireport:

```
$F{incidenciaCat} == null ? $F{f5Hechos} : $F{f5Hechos} == null ? "N/A" : $F{incidenciaCat} == null ? "N/A" : $F{incidenciaCat}
```

Lo que hago es lo siguiente: si **F{incidenciaCat}** es igual a nulo que me ponga **$F{f5Hechos}** si no es nulo me ponga **F{incidenciaCat}** y si **$F{f5Hechos}** también es igual a nulo ponga "**N/A**" el problema es que cuando los dos son nulos no me pone **N/A** me pone tal cual en el reporte **null**

He intentado poner diferente forma la expresión pero no me ha quedado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de tanto batallar por fin encontré la solución la comparto por si a alguien le sirve en un futuro:

```
$F{incidenciaCat} == null && $F{f5Hechos} == null ? "N/A" : $F{f5Hechos} == null ? "N/A" : $F{incidenciaCat}  == null ? $F{f5Hechos} : $F{incidenciaCat}
```

Lo primero que hice fue validar si **$F{incidenciaCat}** es igual a **null** y **$F{f5Hechos}** tambien es igual a **null** entonces pon "**N/A**"